# Why is source-fn failing to find source code in this specific circumstance?

Tags: reflection, clojure, namespaces

This situation is quite tricky to reproduce. First I create a clj file containing:

```
(ns myns)

(defn myfn [x] x)
```

Then I create a second clj file containing:

```
(ns myns2
 (:require [myns :as m]
           [clojure.repl :as repl]))

(comment

 (second (iterate repl/source-fn 'm/myfn))

 (take 2 (iterate repl/source-fn 'm/myfn))

)
```

Then I start a REPL and load the second file in that. Finally I evaluate both comments by sending them to the REPL. The first expression will yield  `"(defn myfn [x] x)"` as expected. However the second expression yields `'(m/myfn nil)`. What is going on here?

Note that fully qualifying 'm/myfn as 'myns/myfn restores matching behavior. Also I understand that iterating source-fn is kinda wacky, but it's the simplest way I know to reproduce the behavior.

Comment: One difference between the two cases: with `second`, `source-fn` runs during the eval step of the REPL; with `take 2`, `source-fn` runs during the print step (due to lazyness).

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your results. Running from a file via `lein test`, I am getting different results:

```
(newline)
(def iii (iterate inc 0))
(spyx (nth iii 0))
(spyx (nth iii 1))
(spyx (nth iii 2))

(defn foo [x] 42)
(def bar (repl/source-fn 'foo))
(newline)
(spyx bar)

(newline)
(spyx  (take 1 (iterate repl/source-fn 'foo)))
(spyx  (take 2 (iterate repl/source-fn 'foo)))

(newline)
(spyx  (first  (iterate repl/source-fn 'foo)))
(spyx  (second (iterate repl/source-fn 'foo)))
```

with results:

```
(nth iii 0) => 0
(nth iii 1) => 1
(nth iii 2) => 2

bar => "(defn foo [x] 42)"

(take 1 (iterate repl/source-fn (quote foo))) => (foo)
(take 2 (iterate repl/source-fn (quote foo))) => (foo "(defn foo [x] 42)")

(first (iterate repl/source-fn (quote foo))) => foo
(second (iterate repl/source-fn (quote foo))) => "(defn foo [x] 42)"
```

Comment: You can't reproduce because you are using spyx. As noted in the comments, the difference is that `iterate` returns a lazy seq which is only printed after evaluation is done. spyx changes that by converting it to a string during the eval phase.